# Diferenciar entre El Valor que ve el usuario y el Value del input o el select

Tags: php, html, css, contentvalues

Vengo desarrollando una WebApp hace un par de semanas, tengo un pequeño inconveniente y es que en el formulario en donde el director del coro debe elegir los cantos que se van a cantar yo almaceno en la base de datos el valor escogido y por tanto almaceno el value, por ejemplo si eligió "Cristo es la Luz" se almacena en la BD el valor: "Cantos/EN0006.html" lo cual está perfecto, pues con ello puedo extraer el archivo con las partituras de dicho canto, el inconveniente, es que tengo otro visual en donde necesito traer el repertorio consolidado por tanto, necesitaria almacenar el nombre del canto y el html que contiene las notas, cómo podria recoger dicha información.

```
<option value="Cantos/EN0004.html">Alto Escúchame - Sol Mayor </option>
<option value="Cantos/EN0005.html">Ay Mira Que Lindo </option>
<option value="Cantos/EN0006.html">Cristo Es La Luz</option>
<option value="Cantos/EN0007.html">Den Gracias Al Señor</option>
<option value="Cantos/EN0008.html">Dios Está Aquí Que Hermoso Es</option>
```

Y me está botando así el consolidado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código de php donde obtengo el value

```
$fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
                $tiempo=$_POST['tiempo'];
                $uniforme=$_POST['uniforme'];
```

Comment: No queda claro en qué contexto ni con qué lenguaje obtienes la información. Si es Javascript, puedes buscar el texto del `option` seleccionado mediante la propiedad `text` del mismo. Convendría que muestres el código donde obtienes el `value`. En cambio, si hablamos del servidor, lo mejor sería otorgar un `ID` a cada canto, ponerlo en el `value` y obtener luego los `.html` y el título de la tabla en la base de datos.

Comment: A. Cedano acabo de editar la publicación y puse parte del códgio que recoge el value.

Comment: No sé si ya lo tienes, pero lo ideal sería que en tu tabla cantos (base de datos) des un ID a cada canto, y que pongas ese ID en el `value` del `option`, luego, con ese ID puedes obtener otros valores, suponiendo que tienes una columna `partitura`, otra columna `titulo` etc. Para construir el consolidado puedes usar atributos `data-*` por ejemplo en los cuales pondrías el `.html` y otras cosas que necesites. Y ya harías todo desde el cliente (Javascript) sin necesidad de volver al servidor.

Comment: Aunque todo depende, pues falta contexto en la pregunta. Por ejemplo, si el flujo es: se presenta la información en el formulario, donde se deben elegir los cantos y luego hay que ir al servidor para insertar esa elección de cantos y generar el consolidado, puedes poner sólo el ID y el título y al momento de la inserción, generas el consolidado desde el contexto del servidor. En cualquier caso, desde el momento en que se construyen los `option` ya puedes tener a mano la información necesaria si usas atributos `data-*`, así, no tienes que volver a consultar la base de datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imaginemos una tabla llamada `canto` con las siguientes columnas:

- **`id`** de tipo auto_increment para identificador único de cada canto
- **`titulo`** para el título del canto
- **`partitura`** para el archivo de la partitura
- **`tipo`** un valor numérico para diferenciar los tipos. Por ejemplo: `1`= `entrada`, `2`= `penitencial`, `3` = `gloria`, etc.

Tú podrías construir el formulario donde se eligen los cantos usando los datos obtenidos en una consulta `SELECT * FROM canto` y usarías el valor de la columna `tipo` para colocar los diferentes `option` de `Entrada`, `Penitencial`, `Gloria`, etc. Y usarías también atributos `data-*` para guardar información adicional en los `option`.

Aquí usaremos los atributos `data-*` para guardar un sólo valor adicional, que sería el html de la partitura, usaremos el atributo `id` para guardar lo que sería el valor de la columna `id` de cada canto y el valor de `text` para el título. Pero imagina que necesitaras guardar más cosas, como el tipo, pues podrías usar otro atributo `data-tipo` y en la lectura crear una estructura de datos ordenada, para construir el consolidado y/o para pasarlo al servidor si fuera necesario.

Veamos un ejemplo simple:

```js
/*Referencia al formulario*/
const form = document.getElementById("form-cantos");

/*Asignamos una función de escucha a los envíos del formulario*/
form.addEventListener("submit", cantosSubmit);

/*
  Función que gestiona los envíos de formulario
  Aquí por ejemplo tú podrías enviar mData al servidor para insertar
  este programa de cantos en la base de datos
  Y lo puedes usar igualmente para crear el consolidado
*/
function cantosSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  /*Objeto que recoge toda la información*/
  let mData = {};

  /*
    Objeto para los valores generales
    tales como fecha, tiempo, etc
  */
  var generalData = {};

  /*Array que contendrá los cantos*/
  let cantos = [];


  /*
    A partir de aquí llenaremos a mData
    Empezaremos por identificar los datos
    generales, tales como fecha, tiempo, etc
  */

  /*
    Primero identificamos los valores únicos
    que pusimos dentro del fieldset
    cuyo id es unique-data
  */
  var singleData = form.querySelectorAll('#unique-data *');

  singleData.forEach((singleItem) => {
    if (singleItem instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
      generalData[singleItem.name] = singleItem.value;

    } else if (singleItem instanceof HTMLSelectElement) {
      var selectedOption = singleItem.options[singleItem.selectedIndex];
      generalData[singleItem.name] = selectedOption.text;
    }
  });

  /*
  Ahora identifica todos los elementos select 
  que se encuentran en el fieldset 
  cuyo id es cantos
  */
  const allSelect = form.querySelectorAll('#cantos > select');

  allSelect.forEach((chantItem) => {
    /*Identifica el option seleccionado de cada select*/
    var selectedOption = chantItem.options[chantItem.selectedIndex];
    /*
      Insertamos en el array cantos
      un objeto con una entrada
      por cada tipo de canto
      y ponemos el título, la partitura, etc
    */
    cantos.push({
      tipo: chantItem.name,
      id: selectedOption.value,
      titulo: selectedOption.text,
      html: selectedOption.dataset.html
    });
  });

  /*
    Ponemos todo dentro de mData
    que será un objeto estructurado
    con toda la información necesaria
    Sea para trabajar en el servidor
    sea para trabajar en el cliente
  */

  mData.general = generalData;
  mData.cantos = cantos;
  console.log(mData);

}
```

```html
<form action="" id="form-cantos">
  <fieldset id="unique-data">
    <label for="fecha">Fecha</label>
    <input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha" placeholder="Escriba la fecha" value="2023-06-18" />
    <br />
    <label for="tiempo">Tiempo litúrgico</label>

    <select name="tiempo" id="tiempo">
      <option value="1">Adviento</option>
      <option value="2">Navidad</option>
      <option value="3">Cuaresma</option>
      <option value="4">Pascua</option>
    </select>

    <br />
    <label for="uniforme">Uniforme</label>

    <select name="uniforme" id="uniforme">
      <option value="1">Camisa Verde</option>
      <option value="2">Todo en Blanco</option>
      <option value="3">Todo en Negro</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <hr />
  <br />
  <fieldset id="cantos">

    <label for="entrada">Entrada</label>

    <select name="entrada" id="entrada">
      <option value="4" data-html="Cantos/EN0004.html">Alto Escúchame - Sol Mayor </option>
      <option value="5" data-html="Cantos/EN0005.html">Ay Mira Que Lindo </option>
      <option value="6" data-html="Cantos/EN0006.html">Cristo Es La Luz</option>
      <option value="7" data-html="Cantos/EN0007.html">Den Gracias Al Señor</option>
      <option value="8" data-html="Cantos/EN0008.html">Dios Está Aquí Que Hermoso Es</option>
    </select>

    <br />

    <label for="penitencial">Penitencial</label>
    <select name="penitencial" id="penitencial">
      <option value="10" data-html="Cantos/PE0006.html">Canto Penitencial 6</option>
      <option value="11" data-html="Cantos/PE0007.html">Canto PE 000 7</option>
      <option value="12" data-html="Cantos/PE0008.html">Canto PE 000 8</option>
    </select>

    <br />

    <label for="gloria">Gloria</label>
    <select name="gloria" id="gloria">
      <option value="13" data-html="Cantos/GL0001.html">Canto Gloria 0001</option>
      <option value="14" data-html="Cantos/GL0002.html">Canto Gloria 0002</option>
      <option value="15" data-html="Cantos/GL0001.html">Canto Gloria 0004</option>
      <option value="16" data-html="Cantos/GL0001.html">Canto Gloria 0005</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <br />

  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">


</form>
```

En este ejemplo, el contenido final de `mData` será un objeto estructurado parecido a este:

```
{
  "general": {
    "fecha": "2023-06-18",
    "tiempo": "Cuaresma",
    "uniforme": "Camisa Verde"
  },
  "cantos": [
    {
      "tipo": "entrada",
      "id": "6",
      "titulo": "Cristo Es La Luz",
      "html": "Cantos/EN0006.html"
    },
    {
      "tipo": "penitencial",
      "id": "11",
      "titulo": "Canto PE 000 7",
      "html": "Cantos/PE0007.html"
    },
    {
      "tipo": "gloria",
      "id": "15",
      "titulo": "Canto Gloria 0004",
      "html": "Cantos/GL0001.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

El cual puedes mandar al servidor o usar en el cliente para construir el consolidado. Veamos un ejemplo donde, al hacer clic en `Enviar` se construye el consolidado debajo del formulario:

```js
/*Referencia al div de consolidado*/
const mDiv = document.getElementById("consolidado");

/*Referencia al formulario*/
const form = document.getElementById("form-cantos");

/*Asignamos una función de escucha a los envíos del formulario*/
form.addEventListener("submit", cantosSubmit);

/*
  Función que gestiona los envíos de formulario
  Aquí por ejemplo tú podrías enviar mData al servidor para insertar
  este programa de cantos en la base de datos
  Y lo puedes usar igualmente para crear el consolidado
*/
function cantosSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  /*Objeto que recoge toda la información*/
  let mData = {};

  /*
    Objeto para los valores generales
    tales como fecha, tiempo, etc
  */
  var generalData = {};

  /*Array que contendrá los cantos*/
  let cantos = [];


  /*
    A partir de aquí llenaremos a mData
    Empezaremos por identificar los datos
    generales, tales como fecha, tiempo, etc
  */

  /*
    Primero identificamos los valores únicos
    que pusimos dentro del fieldset
    cuyo id es unique-data
  */
  var singleData = form.querySelectorAll('#unique-data *');

  singleData.forEach((singleItem) => {
    if (singleItem instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
      generalData[singleItem.name] = singleItem.value;

    } else if (singleItem instanceof HTMLSelectElement) {
      var selectedOption = singleItem.options[singleItem.selectedIndex];
      generalData[singleItem.name] = selectedOption.text;
    }
  });

  /*
  Ahora identifica todos los elementos select 
  que se encuentran en el fieldset 
  cuyo id es cantos
  */
  const allSelect = form.querySelectorAll('#cantos > select');

  allSelect.forEach((chantItem) => {
    /*Identifica el option seleccionado de cada select*/
    var selectedOption = chantItem.options[chantItem.selectedIndex];
    /*
      Insertamos en el array cantos
      un objeto con una entrada
      por cada tipo de canto
      y ponemos el título, la partitura, etc
    */
    cantos.push({
      tipo: chantItem.name,
      id: selectedOption.value,
      titulo: selectedOption.text,
      html: selectedOption.dataset.html
    });
  });

  /*
    Ponemos todo dentro de mData
    que será un objeto estructurado
    con toda la información necesaria
    Sea para trabajar en el servidor
    sea para trabajar en el cliente
  */

  mData.general = generalData;
  mData.cantos = cantos;
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();  fragment.append(document.createElement('hr'));  fragment.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('span'), {
    textContent: "Fecha: "
  }));  fragment.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('span'), {
    textContent: mData.general.fecha
  }));  fragment.append(document.createElement('br'));  fragment.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('span'), {
    textContent: "Tiempo: "
  }));  fragment.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('span'), {
    textContent: mData.general.tiempo
  }));  fragment.append(document.createElement('br'));  fragment.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('span'), {
    textContent: "Uniforme: "
  }));  fragment.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('span'), {
    textContent: mData.general.uniforme
  }));  fragment.append(document.createElement('br'));  fragment.append(document.createElement('br'));  fragment.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('h3'), {
    textContent: "Cantos"
  }));


  for (var key in mData.cantos) {
      fragment.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('h5'), {
      textContent: mData.cantos[key].tipo
    }));  fragment.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('span'), {
      textContent: "Título: "
    }));    fragment.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('span'), {
      textContent: mData.cantos[key].titulo
    }));    fragment.append(document.createElement('br'));    fragment.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('span'), {
      textContent: "Html: "
    }));    fragment.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('span'), {
      textContent: mData.cantos[key].html
    }));

  }

  mDiv.appendChild(fragment);

}
```

```html
<form action="" id="form-cantos">
  <fieldset id="unique-data">
    <label for="fecha">Fecha</label>
    <input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha" placeholder="Escriba la fecha" value="2023-06-18" />
    <br />
    <label for="tiempo">Tiempo litúrgico</label>

    <select name="tiempo" id="tiempo">
      <option value="1">Adviento</option>
      <option value="2">Navidad</option>
      <option value="3">Cuaresma</option>
      <option value="4">Pascua</option>
    </select>

    <br />
    <label for="uniforme">Uniforme</label>

    <select name="uniforme" id="uniforme">
      <option value="1">Camisa Verde</option>
      <option value="2">Todo en Blanco</option>
      <option value="3">Todo en Negro</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <hr />
  <br />
  <fieldset id="cantos">

    <label for="entrada">Entrada</label>

    <select name="entrada" id="entrada">
      <option value="4" data-html="Cantos/EN0004.html">Alto Escúchame - Sol Mayor </option>
      <option value="5" data-html="Cantos/EN0005.html">Ay Mira Que Lindo </option>
      <option value="6" data-html="Cantos/EN0006.html">Cristo Es La Luz</option>
      <option value="7" data-html="Cantos/EN0007.html">Den Gracias Al Señor</option>
      <option value="8" data-html="Cantos/EN0008.html">Dios Está Aquí Que Hermoso Es</option>
    </select>

    <br />

    <label for="penitencial">Penitencial</label>
    <select name="penitencial" id="penitencial">
      <option value="10" data-html="Cantos/PE0006.html">Canto Penitencial 6</option>
      <option value="11" data-html="Cantos/PE0007.html">Canto PE 000 7</option>
      <option value="12" data-html="Cantos/PE0008.html">Canto PE 000 8</option>
    </select>

    <br />

    <label for="gloria">Gloria</label>
    <select name="gloria" id="gloria">
      <option value="13" data-html="Cantos/GL0001.html">Canto Gloria 0001</option>
      <option value="14" data-html="Cantos/GL0002.html">Canto Gloria 0002</option>
      <option value="15" data-html="Cantos/GL0001.html">Canto Gloria 0004</option>
      <option value="16" data-html="Cantos/GL0001.html">Canto Gloria 0005</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <br />

  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>

<div id="consolidado"></div>
```

Comment: Padre A. Cedano, mil bendiciones, acabo de leer su respuesta a mi pregunta, y de antemano mil disculpas pues soy nuevo en cuanto al tema de la programación y podrían ser preguntas un poco elementos, sé que no es el espacio para ello pero he leído la descripción de su perfil y me ha parecido increible su testimonio de vida, me alegra que me pueda colaborar, pues este proyecto es para Dios y es el quien lo ha puesto en este camino para ayudarme a sacarlo adelante, Dios bendiga su caminar vocacional, estaré revisando el código y comentando esta publicación. Dios le bendiga ♥ Saludos de Colombia